# Is there a TO_DATE() time equivalent function in Google Sheets ( something like TO_TIME() )?

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

I need to convert a text formated input time to the time format with a formula on an entire column.

The only way I found to do it was with combining `TIME()` and 3 nested `MID()` from [this source article](https://www.modernschoolbus.com/convert-text-to-date-in-google-sheets/) doing the same with `DATE()` :

```
=TIME(MID(K14,1,2),MID(K14,4,2),MID(K14,7,2))
```

[image: TIME(MID(K14,1,2),MID(K14,4,2),MID(K14,7,2))]

The source article example with `DATE()`:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,3,2))
```

[image: =DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,3,2))]

Previoulsy in the same source article is shown this example with `=TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(value))` :

[image: =TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(value)]

The `=TIME(MID(K14,1,2),MID(K14,4,2),MID(K14,7,2))` approach works well, but given the `TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(value))` "date only related nature" I was wondering if some similar approach without the need to resort to nested `MID()` 's is possible.

I tought something like `TO_TIME(TIMEVALUE(value))` with *'TO_TIME()'* would be available since the `TIMEVALUE()` equivalent to the `DATEVALUE()` is supplied but I did not find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
=--K14
```

And then format the cell as time. You should also be able to format the cell K14 as time directly.

Comment: thanks I did not know this `--` was possible. I just checked and it returns the same value as the `TIMEVALUE()`. That's for sure a quicker and simpler way to get the timevalue and of interest, however it would be best a suggestion if possible without the 2nd manual format step. As a formula similar to the `DATE(DATEVALUE())` would spare having to remember and potentially correct formating for new projects or of an imported range or importedxml data etc. gets corrupted upon data update etc. Also for large sheets to prevent having to dig into cells in such cases.

Comment: I don't think there's another way to do it other than the method you are already using.